# Segmentation fault on a model using only EUF

Tags: segmentation-fault, z3

I  am using Z3 version 4.4.0 on an Ubuntu 15.04 machine. The following model seems to cause a segmentation  fault :

```
; mapping  
(declare-sort  Any   0 )
(declare-sort ProcBase 0)
(declare-fun Any_of_ProcBase ( ProcBase ) Any )
; Sort Real is default in smtlib 2.0. 
(declare-fun Any_of_Real ( Real ) Any )
(declare-fun execTime_of_ProcBase ( ProcBase ) Real )
(define-fun specA_of_ProcBase ( ( S ProcBase) ) Bool true ) 
(define-fun specG_of_ProcBase ( ( S ProcBase) ) Bool  ( not ( specA_of_ProcBase S ) ) )
(define-fun composedG_of_ProcBase ( ( S ProcBase ) ) Bool false  ) 
(define-fun composedA_of_ProcBase ( ( S ProcBase ) ) Bool true ) 
(declare-sort SwTask 0)
(declare-fun Any_of_SwTask ( SwTask ) Any )
(declare-fun requiredOps_of_SwTask ( SwTask ) Real )
(declare-fun desiredPeriod_of_SwTask ( SwTask ) Real )
(declare-fun complexity_of_SwTask ( SwTask ) Real )
(declare-fun execTime_of_SwTask ( SwTask ) Real )
(define-fun PeriodAssumption_of_SwTask ( (S SwTask) ) Bool ( and  ( >=  ( desiredPeriod_of_SwTask S  )  ( execTime_of_SwTask S  )  )  ( >=  ( complexity_of_SwTask S  )  ( to_real  0  )  )  )  )
(define-fun Ops_of_SwTask ( (S SwTask) ) Bool  ( =  ( requiredOps_of_SwTask S  )  ( complexity_of_SwTask S  )  )  )
(define-fun specA_of_SwTask ( ( S SwTask) ) Bool ( PeriodAssumption_of_SwTask S ) )
(define-fun specG_of_SwTask ( ( S SwTask) ) Bool ( or ( Ops_of_SwTask S ) ( not ( specA_of_SwTask S ) ) ) )
(define-fun composedG_of_SwTask ( ( S SwTask ) ) Bool false  ) 
(define-fun composedA_of_SwTask ( ( S SwTask ) ) Bool true ) 
(declare-sort Processor 0)
(declare-fun Any_of_Processor ( Processor ) Any )
(declare-fun ProcBase_of_Processor ( Processor ) ProcBase )
(declare-fun opsPerSec_of_Processor ( Processor ) Real )
(declare-fun requriedOps_of_Processor ( Processor ) Real )
(define-fun G_of_Processor ( (S Processor) ) Bool  ( =  ( execTime_of_ProcBase ( ProcBase_of_Processor S )   )  ( / ( requriedOps_of_Processor S  )  ( opsPerSec_of_Processor S  )  )  )  )
(define-fun specA_of_Processor ( ( S Processor) ) Bool true ) 
(define-fun specG_of_Processor ( ( S Processor) ) Bool ( or ( G_of_Processor S ) ( not ( specA_of_Processor S ) ) ) )
(define-fun composedG_of_Processor ( ( S Processor ) ) Bool false  ) 
(define-fun composedA_of_Processor ( ( S Processor ) ) Bool true ) 
(declare-sort Mapping 0)
(declare-fun Any_of_Mapping ( Mapping ) Any )
(declare-sort Array_t_SwTask_t 0)
(declare-fun Any_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( Array_t_SwTask_t ) Any )
; Sort Int is default in smtlib 2.0. 
(declare-fun Any_of_Int ( Int ) Any )
(declare-fun select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( Array_t_SwTask_t Int ) SwTask )
(declare-fun size_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( Array_t_SwTask_t ) Int )
(define-fun specA_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( ( S Array_t_SwTask_t) ) Bool true ) 
(define-fun specG_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( ( S Array_t_SwTask_t) ) Bool  ( not ( specA_of_Array_t_SwTask_t S ) ) )
(define-fun composedG_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( ( S Array_t_SwTask_t ) ) Bool false  ) 
(define-fun composedA_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( ( S Array_t_SwTask_t ) ) Bool true ) 
(declare-fun tasks_of_Mapping ( Mapping ) Array_t_SwTask_t )
(declare-sort Array_t_Processor_t 0)
(declare-fun Any_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( Array_t_Processor_t ) Any )
(declare-fun select_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( Array_t_Processor_t Int ) Processor )
(declare-fun size_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( Array_t_Processor_t ) Int )
(define-fun specA_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( ( S Array_t_Processor_t) ) Bool true ) 
(define-fun specG_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( ( S Array_t_Processor_t) ) Bool  ( not ( specA_of_Array_t_Processor_t S ) ) )
(define-fun composedG_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( ( S Array_t_Processor_t ) ) Bool false  ) 
(define-fun composedA_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( ( S Array_t_Processor_t ) ) Bool true ) 
(declare-fun procs_of_Mapping ( Mapping ) Array_t_Processor_t )
(declare-sort Array_t_Real_t 0)
(declare-fun Any_of_Array_t_Real_t ( Array_t_Real_t ) Any )
(declare-fun select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( Array_t_Real_t Int ) Real )
(declare-fun size_of_Array_t_Real_t ( Array_t_Real_t ) Int )
(define-fun specA_of_Array_t_Real_t ( ( S Array_t_Real_t) ) Bool true ) 
(define-fun specG_of_Array_t_Real_t ( ( S Array_t_Real_t) ) Bool  ( not ( specA_of_Array_t_Real_t S ) ) )
(define-fun composedG_of_Array_t_Real_t ( ( S Array_t_Real_t ) ) Bool false  ) 
(define-fun composedA_of_Array_t_Real_t ( ( S Array_t_Real_t ) ) Bool true ) 
(declare-sort Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t 0)
(declare-fun Any_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ) Any )
(declare-fun select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t Int ) Array_t_Real_t )
(declare-fun size_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ) Int )
(define-fun specA_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( ( S Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t) ) Bool true ) 
(define-fun specG_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( ( S Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t) ) Bool  ( not ( specA_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t S ) ) )
(define-fun composedG_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( ( S Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ) ) Bool false  ) 
(define-fun composedA_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( ( S Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ) ) Bool true ) 
(declare-fun requiredOps_of_Mapping ( Mapping ) Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t )
(declare-fun mappedTo_of_Mapping (   SwTask Processor )  Bool  )
(define-fun MappingConstraints_of_Mapping ( (S Mapping) ) Bool ( and ( and  ( =  ( size_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )  )  ( size_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( procs_of_Mapping S )  )  ) ( and ( and ( and ( and ( and ( and ( and  ( =  ( size_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   0  )   )  ( size_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )  )  )  ( =  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   0  )   -1   )  ( to_real  0  )  )  ) ( and ( and ( and  ( =>   ( mappedTo_of_Mapping S   ( select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )   0  )   ( select_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( procs_of_Mapping S )   0  )  )  ( =  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   0  )   0   )  ( to_real  ( + ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   0  )   -1   )  ( requiredOps_of_SwTask ( select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )   0  )   )  )  )  )  ) ( =>  ( not  ( mappedTo_of_Mapping S   ( select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )   0  )   ( select_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( procs_of_Mapping S )   0  )  )  )  ( =  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   0  )   0   )  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   0  )   -1   )  )  )  ) ( and  ( =>   ( mappedTo_of_Mapping S   ( select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )   1  )   ( select_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( procs_of_Mapping S )   0  )  )  ( =  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   0  )   1   )  ( to_real  ( + ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   0  )   0   )  ( requiredOps_of_SwTask ( select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )   1  )   )  )  )  )  ) ( =>  ( not  ( mappedTo_of_Mapping S   ( select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )   1  )   ( select_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( procs_of_Mapping S )   0  )  )  )  ( =  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   0  )   1   )  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   0  )   0   )  )  )  )  ) ( and  ( =>   ( mappedTo_of_Mapping S   ( select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )   2  )   ( select_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( procs_of_Mapping S )   0  )  )  ( =  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   0  )   2   )  ( to_real  ( + ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   0  )   1   )  ( requiredOps_of_SwTask ( select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )   2  )   )  )  )  )  ) ( =>  ( not  ( mappedTo_of_Mapping S   ( select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )   2  )   ( select_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( procs_of_Mapping S )   0  )  )  )  ( =  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   0  )   2   )  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   0  )   1   )  )  )  )  )  )  ( =  ( requriedOps_of_Processor ( select_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( procs_of_Mapping S )   0  )   )  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   0  )   ( - ( size_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )  )  1  )   )  )  )  ( =  ( size_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   1  )   )  ( size_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )  )  )  )  ( =  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   1  )   -1   )  ( to_real  0  )  )  ) ( and ( and ( and  ( =>   ( mappedTo_of_Mapping S   ( select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )   0  )   ( select_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( procs_of_Mapping S )   1  )  )  ( =  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   1  )   0   )  ( to_real  ( + ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   1  )   -1   )  ( requiredOps_of_SwTask ( select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )   0  )   )  )  )  )  ) ( =>  ( not  ( mappedTo_of_Mapping S   ( select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )   0  )   ( select_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( procs_of_Mapping S )   1  )  )  )  ( =  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   1  )   0   )  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   1  )   -1   )  )  )  ) ( and  ( =>   ( mappedTo_of_Mapping S   ( select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )   1  )   ( select_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( procs_of_Mapping S )   1  )  )  ( =  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   1  )   1   )  ( to_real  ( + ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   1  )   0   )  ( requiredOps_of_SwTask ( select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )   1  )   )  )  )  )  ) ( =>  ( not  ( mappedTo_of_Mapping S   ( select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )   1  )   ( select_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( procs_of_Mapping S )   1  )  )  )  ( =  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   1  )   1   )  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   1  )   0   )  )  )  )  ) ( and  ( =>   ( mappedTo_of_Mapping S   ( select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )   2  )   ( select_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( procs_of_Mapping S )   1  )  )  ( =  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   1  )   2   )  ( to_real  ( + ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   1  )   1   )  ( requiredOps_of_SwTask ( select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )   2  )   )  )  )  )  ) ( =>  ( not  ( mappedTo_of_Mapping S   ( select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )   2  )   ( select_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( procs_of_Mapping S )   1  )  )  )  ( =  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   1  )   2   )  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   1  )   1   )  )  )  )  )  )  ( =  ( requriedOps_of_Processor ( select_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( procs_of_Mapping S )   1  )   )  ( select_of_Array_t_Real_t ( select_of_Array_t_Array_t_Real_t_t ( requiredOps_of_Mapping S )   1  )   ( - ( size_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping S )  )  1  )   )  )  )  ) ( forall  ( ( sw SwTask ) ) ( exists  ( ( p Processor ) )  ( mappedTo_of_Mapping S   sw   p  )  )  )  )  )
(define-fun specA_of_Mapping ( ( S Mapping) ) Bool true ) 
(define-fun specG_of_Mapping ( ( S Mapping) ) Bool ( or ( MappingConstraints_of_Mapping S ) ( not ( specA_of_Mapping S ) ) ) )
(define-fun composedG_of_Mapping ( ( S Mapping ) ) Bool false  ) 
(define-fun composedA_of_Mapping ( ( S Mapping ) ) Bool true ) 
(declare-sort System 0)
(declare-fun Any_of_System ( System ) Any )
(declare-fun proc1_of_System ( System ) Processor )
(declare-fun proc2_of_System ( System ) Processor )
(declare-fun task1_of_System ( System ) SwTask )
(declare-fun task2_of_System ( System ) SwTask )
(declare-fun task3_of_System ( System ) SwTask )
(declare-fun mapping_of_System ( System ) Mapping )
(define-fun Conn_of_System ( (S System) ) Bool ( and ( and ( and ( and ( and ( and ( and ( and ( and ( and ( and ( and ( and ( and  ( =  ( select_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( procs_of_Mapping ( mapping_of_System S )  )   0   )  ( proc1_of_System S  )  )  ( =  ( select_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( procs_of_Mapping ( mapping_of_System S )  )   1   )  ( proc2_of_System S  )  )  )  ( =  ( select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping ( mapping_of_System S )  )   0   )  ( task1_of_System S  )  )  )  ( =  ( select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping ( mapping_of_System S )  )   1   )  ( task2_of_System S  )  )  )  ( =  ( select_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping ( mapping_of_System S )  )   2   )  ( task3_of_System S  )  )  )  ( =  ( size_of_Array_t_Processor_t ( procs_of_Mapping ( mapping_of_System S )  )   )  2  )  )  ( =  ( size_of_Array_t_SwTask_t ( tasks_of_Mapping ( mapping_of_System S )  )   )  3  )  )  ( =  ( complexity_of_SwTask ( task1_of_System S )  )  ( to_real  100  )  )  )  ( =  ( complexity_of_SwTask ( task2_of_System S )  )  ( to_real  100  )  )  )  ( =  ( complexity_of_SwTask ( task3_of_System S )  )  ( to_real  100  )  )  )  ( =  ( opsPerSec_of_Processor ( proc1_of_System S )  )  ( to_real  200  )  )  )  ( =  ( opsPerSec_of_Processor ( proc2_of_System S )  )  ( to_real  200  )  )  )  ( =  ( desiredPeriod_of_SwTask ( task1_of_System S )  )  ( to_real  1  )  )  )  ( =  ( desiredPeriod_of_SwTask ( task2_of_System S )  )  ( to_real  1  )  )  )  ( =  ( desiredPeriod_of_SwTask ( task3_of_System S )  )  ( to_real  1  )  )  )  )
(define-fun specA_of_System ( ( S System) ) Bool true ) 
(define-fun specG_of_System ( ( S System) ) Bool  ( not ( specA_of_System S ) ) )
(define-fun composedG_of_System ( ( S System ) ) Bool ( and  true  ( Conn_of_System S ) ( => ( specA_of_Processor ( proc1_of_System S ) )( specG_of_Processor ( proc1_of_System S ) ) ) ( => ( specA_of_Processor ( proc2_of_System S ) )( specG_of_Processor ( proc2_of_System S ) ) ) ( => ( specA_of_SwTask ( task1_of_System S ) )( specG_of_SwTask ( task1_of_System S ) ) ) ( => ( specA_of_SwTask ( task2_of_System S ) )( specG_of_SwTask ( task2_of_System S ) ) ) ( => ( specA_of_SwTask ( task3_of_System S ) )( specG_of_SwTask ( task3_of_System S ) ) ) ( => ( specA_of_Mapping ( mapping_of_System S ) )( specG_of_Mapping ( mapping_of_System S ) ) )   ) ) 
(define-fun composedA_of_System ( ( S System ) ) Bool  ( or ( and  true  ( specA_of_Processor ( proc1_of_System S ) )( specA_of_Processor ( proc2_of_System S ) )( specA_of_SwTask ( task1_of_System S ) )( specA_of_SwTask ( task2_of_System S ) )( specA_of_SwTask ( task3_of_System S ) )( specA_of_Mapping ( mapping_of_System S ) ) ) (not  ( composedG_of_System S ) )  ) ) 
; check implementality for System
(declare-const S_System System )
(assert ( composedA_of_System  S_System ) )
(assert ( composedG_of_System  S_System ) )
(check-sat)
```

The problem seems to be caused by the function `MappingConstraints_of_Mapping`. If the sum operator in that function is removed by removing the second operand, then Z3 has no problem solving this instance.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this segfault using the latest unstable version. Instead, I get multiple errors, the first being this:

```
(error "line 74 column 729: Wrong number of arguments (3) passed to function (declare-fun mappedTo_of_Mapping (SwTask Processor) Bool)")
```

Could you retry this with the latest unstable? If there are still problems please open a new issue in the [Z3 issue tracker](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues).